# matching two column by numbers, in Knime

Tags: expression, string-matching, knime

I want to “match” two column based on numbers, create new column with those matching True and those not matching is False for example, two column are “Node id” and “IDs”

| Node id | IDs | Matching |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
| DB Query:0:0:188 | [(#0), (#188)] | for eg, here 0 0 188 are matched so its True |
| DB Query:197:0:122 | [(#197), (#0), (#135)] | here 197 0 135 not matched so its False |

I want to write query in Column Expression or Rule Engine in Knime, can anybody help ? :slight_smile:

I tried doing it in Column Expression with this query but cant figure it, how to write it further

if (column("IDs").=== 0:0:188 ){

"True"

}

else "False"

Comment: This is a fairly complex piece of logic and I don't think you'll do it in a single KNIME node unless you use a script node and write some Java or Python for it. You should be able to achieve it with a combination of nodes though. First question: are there always three numbers in the `Node id` column, but there may be fewer than three in the `IDs` column?

Comment: Already done with it in Knime, it was complex but doable